# Export Outlook 2010 Contacts on Exchange Server Mail List

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a mailing list that is on an exchange server. I can view the members on the mailing list but I would like to be able to export the member's name and email address data from the list.  As the list is on a server, even though I save the contacts in my Outlook there doesn't appear to be able any way to extract the individual information for the members.

Comment: you can probably get it best through the back-end, Active Directory most likely.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "mailing list" In Exchange server. Are you referring to an Address Book, your Contacts, Public Folder Contacts, a Distribution Group or your Suggested Contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Open contacts list from Public Folder contact lists and save as .txt format.  It will export name & email in a text file. However, exporting public folder contacts to pst is a preferred option.